# Keras: Unable to allocate 3.75 GiB for an array with shape

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a 1D-Convolutional neural network but I'm faced with the Error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.75 GiB for an array with shape (1259, 400001) and data type float64
```

As I read it's probably because of the overcommit handling mode of my system. However, I'm not sure weither it's because of me not appropriate reshaping my array to the appropriate batch size.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((400001, len(X_train)))#.astype(int)
Y_train = np.transpose(Y_train).reshape((-1,2224))
#Y_test = Y_test.reshape((-1,400001))


BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 10

#input_shape = (1, len(X_train))

def model():
    m = Sequential()
    m.add(Conv1D(40001, 7, activation = 'relu'))#input_shape = input_shape
    m.add(Conv1D(400001, 2, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=7))
    m.add(Conv1D(64, 7, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(Conv1D(64, 5, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
        
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-2/EPOCHS)
    m.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
    # Fit data to model m
    m.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = EPOCHS, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test))
    m.summary()
       
    test_loss, test_acc = m.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose = 0)
    print('Test loss:', test_loss[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', test_acc[1])
    
    #m.predict()

mod = model()
```

Comment: Seems like you do not have enough memory. Do you have enough memory to fit the model?

Comment: It might be that the reshaping already breaks things (don't know the problem so can't tell you whether you should reshape), but if it doesn't, adding a Conv1D layer with thousands of filters definitely will. The number of filters is the number of 'features' that the conv layer will output at each time step.